# Powershell logging to lost network location: FileStream won't reconnect/flush

Tags: powershell, filestream

I am working on a script logging solution for an install script that has many tasks and long processing times, and I am trying to address the issue of network dropout. I am also moving to a `StreamWriter` based approach vs my old `Add-Content` approach for performance reasons.
The problem I am having is that once the network drops out, the StreamWriter doesn't reconnect. So, first question is, CAN I reconnect, or is this a limitation of StreamWriter? The fact that the StreamWriter has a cache that can be Flushed makes me think I may be doing a bunch of work to recreate functionality that is already there.
And second, I am starting to think a simpler/better solution is simply to write the log to a local folder, so the log is always complete, then simply attempt to copy that to the network location for progress review. I had been thinking about implementing parallel logs, so a loss of the network would still leave the local copy complete. Curious if anyone else looks at this and says "Well, YEAH, dufus, obviously."

```
function Get-PxLogFile {
    return $script:pxLogFile
}
function Set-PxLogFile {
    param (
        [string]$path
    )

    if (Test-Path $path) {
        Remove-Item $path -force
    }
    [string]$script:pxLogFile= $path
}
function Get-PxLogWriter {
    $logFile = Get-PxLogFile
    if (-not $script:pxFileStream) {
        $script:pxFileStream = New-Object io.fileStream $logFile, 'Append', 'Write', 'Read'
        $script:pxlogWriter = New-Object io.streamWriter $script:pxFileStream
    } elseif ($script:pxFileStream.name -ne $logFile) {
        $script:pxFileStream = New-Object io.fileStream $logFile, 'Append', 'Write', 'Read'
        $script:pxlogWriter = New-Object io.streamWriter $script:pxFileStream
    }
    return $script:pxlogWriter
}

function Dispose-PxLogFile {
    $script:pxlogWriter.Dispose()
    $script:pxFileStream.Dispose()
    $script:pxFileStream = $null
    $script:pxlogWriter = $null
}

# Shared
function Get-PxDeferredLog {
    return ,$script:deferredLog # , keeps PS from unrolling a single item array into a string
}
function Set-PxDeferredLog {
    param (
        [collections.arrayList]$deferredLog
    )
    [collections.arrayList]$script:deferredLog = $deferredLog
}
function Get-PxDeferredLogTimes {
    return ($script:deferredLogTimes -join ', ')
}


function Finalize-PxLogFile {
    $logWriter = Get-PxLogWriter
    if (($deferredLog = Get-PxDeferredLog).count -gt 0) {
        $abandonTime = (Get-Date) + (New-TimeSpan -seconds:3)
        $logWriter = Get-PxLogWriter
        :lastChanceLogWindow do {
            $deferredLog = Get-PxDeferredLog
            :deferredItemsWrite do {
                try {
                    $logWriter.WriteLine($deferredLog[0])
                    if ($deferredLog.count -gt 0) {
                        $deferredLog.RemoveAt(0)
                    } else {
                        break :lastChanceWindow
                    }
                } catch {
                    break :deferredItemsWrite
                }
            } while ($deferredLog.count -gt 0)
            Set-PxDeferredLog $deferredLog
            if ($deferredLog.count -eq 0) {
                break :lastChanceWindow
            }
            if ((Get-Date) -gt $abandonTime) {
                break :lastChanceLogWindow
            }
        } while ((Get-Date) -lt $abandonTime)

        if ($deferredLog) {
            Write-Host "Failed to write all log entries"
        }
    }
    $script:deferredLogItems = $script:deferredLogTimes = $null
}

function Add-PxLogFileContent {
    param (
        [string]$string
    )

    $logWriter = Get-PxLogWriter

    # Nested Functions
    function Add-PxDeferredLogItem {
        param (
            [string]$item
        )
        if (-not $script:deferredLog) {
            [collections.arrayList]$script:deferredLog = New-Object collections.arrayList
        }
        if ($script:deferredLog.count -eq 0) {
            Start-PxDeferredLogTime
        }
        [void]$script:deferredLog.Add($item)
    }

    function Start-PxDeferredLogTime {
        if (-not $script:deferredLogTimes) {
            [collections.arrayList]$script:deferredLogTimes = New-Object collections.arrayList
        }
        if ((-not $script:deferredLogTimes) -or (-not $script:deferredLogTimes[-1].EndsWith('-'))) {
            [void]$script:deferredLogTimes.Add("$((Get-Date).ToString('T'))-")
        }
    }
    function Stop-PxDeferredLogTime {
        if ($script:deferredLogTimes[-1].EndsWith('-')) {
            $script:deferredLogTimes[-1] = "$($script:deferredLogTimes[-1])$((Get-Date).ToString('T'))"
        }
    }

    $deferredLogProcessed = $false
    if ([collections.arrayList]$deferredLog = Get-PxDeferredLog) {
        $deferredLogProcessed = $true
        :deferredItemsWrite do {
            try {
                $logWriter.WriteLine($deferredLog[0])
                $logWriter.Flush()
                $deferredLog.RemoveAt(0)
            } catch {
                break :deferredItemsWrite
            }
        } while ($deferredLog.count -gt 0)
        if ($deferredLog.count -eq 0) {
            $deferredLogPending = $false
        } else {
            $deferredLogPending = $true
        }
        Set-PxDeferredLog $deferredLog
    } else {
        $deferredLogPending = $false
    }

    if (-not $deferredLogPending) {
        try {
            if ($logWriter.WriteLine($string)) {
                $logWriter.Flush()
            }
            if ($deferredLogProcessed) {Stop-PxDeferredLogTime}
        } catch {
            Add-PxDeferredLogItem $string
            Write-Host "Failed: $(Get-Date)`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    } else {
        Add-PxDeferredLogItem $string
    }
}


### MAIN 
Clear-Host
$script:deferredLogItems = $script:deferredLogTimes = $null
$logPath = '\\px\Content'

Write-Host 'logTest1.txt'
$startTime = Get-Date
$endTime = $startTime + (New-TimeSpan -minutes:5)
#Set-PxLogFile "$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($env:TEMP))\logTest1.txt"
Set-PxLogFile "$logPath\logTest1.txt"
do {
    Add-PxLogFileContent "logged: $(Get-Date)"
    Start-SLeep -s:10
} while ((Get-Date) -lt $endTime) 
Finalize-PxLogFile


Write-Host 'logTest2.txt'
$startTime = Get-Date
$endTime = $startTime + (New-TimeSpan -minutes:5)
#Set-PxLogFile "$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($env:TEMP))\logTest2.txt"
Set-PxLogFile "$logPath\logTest2.txt"
do {
    Add-PxLogFileContent "logged: $(Get-Date)"
    Start-SLeep -s:10
} while ((Get-Date) -lt $endTime) 

if ([string]$deferredLogTimes = Get-PxDeferredLogTimes) {
    Add-PxLogFileContent "Deferred logging time ranges: $deferredLogTimes"
}
Finalize-PxLogFile

Dispose-PxLogFile
```